# java inputStream Freezing

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream

Im trying to run a thread that goes to a socket, grabs the input stream, and reads it. Im creating hundreds of these threads and have set the timeout for reading and yet the thread still stays at the read() line.

```
public void readPack() {

socket.setSoTimeout(4*1000);

if (socket.isConnected()) {


     buffer parse = new buffer();
     parse.addByte((byte) skt.getInputStream().read());
     parseIncoming(parse);
}


} catch (Exception e) {}

}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to even guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Strange code. You create a buffer, read one byte into it, then parse that byte, then repeat the whole process. One byte surely doesn't take much parsing. You are never checking for -1 from the read so this loop will spin endlessly when the peer disconnects. And finally Socket.isConnected() isn't a useful test, and specifically it doesn't detect the peer disconnecting.

Comment: the while is suppose to be an if, just trying to pick up one byte

Answer (score 0):

Call `skt.available()`, and then call read that many times, or use `skt.read(byte[])`. Other wise `skt.read()` will block. The timeout your setting is to connect to the socket, and not a read timeout.

Comment: The timeout he is setting is a read timeout, not a connect timeout.